# Swift reloadData on TableView

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uitableview

I am reloading my TableView when I receive data from Facebook's SDK/API. I want to populate my tableView with that data, but when I call `self.friendsTable.reloadData()` it is really laggy and slow, even when I added it to `dispatch_async()`.

This is the `getFriends()` function in my `FacebookController`.

```
func getFriends(){
        let friendsReq = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: nil)
        friendsReq.startWithCompletionHandler{
            (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil{
                let alertCtrl = UIAlertController(title: "Geen vrienden?", message: "We konden geen vrienden vinden..", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
                let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Begrepen!", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                    // Do something?
                })
                alertCtrl.addAction(confirmAction)
                self.presentViewController(alertCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let data = result["data"]
                for friend in data as! NSArray{
                    self.friendsNames.append(friend["name"] as! String)
                    self.friendsImages.append((friend["picture"]!!["data"]!!["url"] as? String)!)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView(self.friendsTable, numberOfRowsInSection: self.friendsNames.count)
                    self.friendsTable.reloadData()
                    return
                })

            }

        }
    }
```

And here is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell") as! FriendTableViewCell

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let img = self.friendsImages[indexPath.row]
            let imgUrl = NSURL(string: img)
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgUrl!)
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            cell.friendName.text = self.friendsNames[indexPath.row]
            cell.friendImage.image = image
        })

        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Do something
        return self.friendsNames.count
    }
```

Comment: Loading data into UIViews on cellForRow makes no sense to be inside a dispatch block

Comment: Can you post all of your other `UITabieViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` method implementations? Maybe it's something in one of them

Comment: Posted the `numberOfRowsInSection` too

Comment: @jbehrens94: in your cell configuration, try leaving `cell.friendName.text = self.friendsNames[indexPath.row]` only, commenting the next one and the previous 4 lines

Comment: Oh, that really did help! It's quick and snappy!

Answer (score 3):

The `dispatch_async` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is really unneeded - and probably that's the source of your problems.

That method is invoked internally when populating the table, so it can be given for granted that it is executed in the main thread.

Instead in your implementation the cell is created or dequeued, returned, and at a later time it's configured, because the closure passed to `dispatch_async` is executed out of the flow.

Just get rid of `dispatch_async` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and it should work.

Comment: I did remove that, but it's still really really really slow, the tableView takes literally seconds te scroll.

Comment: is it slow during scrolling (meaning it takes long for the table to move) or does it scroll normally, but it's slow in updating the data in each cell?

Comment: It is really slow during scrolling, taking long for the table to move.

Comment: @Woodstock: not sure, but I think internally the `startWithCompletionHandler` doesn't run on the main thread, so it's probably not needed

Comment: @jbehrens94: that might indicate that the problem is somewhere else - such as something eating CPU on the main thread. Look at the code executed after the `getFriends()` call - or do some profiling to figure that out

Comment: CPU gets to 5/6% when scrolling, Memory stays stable at 40MB. This is pretty weird, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed... if you comment the `reloadData` invocation, do you see any change (besides the table not being reloaded)?

Comment: if I comment `reloadData`, it's all superfast and snappy. CPU at 2~4%, memory at 40MB.